# top navbar on android kendoui mobile app

Tags: android, kendo-mobile

I'm writing a **KendoUI Mobile** app for **Android**.
I add these style rules to put the navbar at the top of the screen.

```
/* visulaizza il titolo nella navbar */ 
.km-android .km-navbar .km-view-title {
    visibility: visible;
}

/* navbar in alto */
.km-android .km-view {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
```

Those work well when all run in browser preview but, after the app was build, on the device the navbar appears at the bottom.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule are incomplete. Use that:

```
.km-root .km-android .km-view {
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
```

You can watch other style tricks from this link 
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/application

Answer (score 0):

Where do you place these CSS rules? Seems they don't get included in the build for some reason.

Comment: i've a `www` dir that contains `index.html` and other subdirs:
 - `styles`: contain kendoui css data;
 - `js`: contain kendoui javascript data;
 - `css`: contain a css file (`kendo.android.edit.css`) with those rules.

in `index.html` into `head` tag i add a link to my css:
`
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="css/kendo.android.edit.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     ...
    </head>
 ...
</html>
`

Comment: Sounds okay and should be working. Can you post a support ticket on kendoui.com and send the app over, so that we can take a look? Or you can prepare a sample app that reproduces the issue and post it here?